# Measuring Progess in Academia Solely By Using a Person's Publications?

Tags: academic-life, productivity

Over the last couple of days, I happened to exchange comments with users who disagreed with me about the fact that *progress in academia is based on  publications*. Am I missing something here?

**What I mean by progress**:
Simply put, progress here means to obtain promotions. To go from postdoc to lecturer and so on.

Comment: Perhaps it is in the difficulty in defining 'progress' uniquely. Publications are one way to document 'progress' in contributing to the field. So are conference talks, seminars, etc. However, 'progress' could also be getting grants, being promoted or given tenure, increasing one's citation count of h-index, finally making the front page of the New York Times (for good reasons, not bad!), making obvious positive contributions to somebody's life (student, post-doc, department secretary), etc. To suggest that publications alone are the sole metric of progress or performance is misleading at best.

Comment: @JonCuster All those things you mentioned, such as getting funded, are given based on someone's past publications.

Comment: Networking and soft skills contribute greatly to the things Jon mentioned, even without past publications.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you actually asking?

Comment: In any case, to insist that "progress" means just "promotions" is an abuse of the sense of the word, I think. Asking directly about "measuring promotions by publications" would be more honest, if still misguided.

Comment: @paulgarrett Becoming a Professor is not a progress? How you become a professor? by a promotion. You are living in a capitalist world, promotion is a form/part of progress.

Answer (score 6):

Trying to measure success with *any* metric in life is a dangerous thing.

As soon as there is a metric, people will game it or lose sight on its original meaning. For example, in academia, this results in people trying to publish the smallest unit of work possible or trying to go for short term successes rather than the big picture. Additionally, things like peer review have already been [shown](http://blog.mrtz.org/2014/12/15/the-nips-experiment.html) to have a huge influence of luck so it makes it silly to compare.

Publishing can be a very motivating metric, but you have to be careful when you begin conflating it with *progress* or *success*.

Answer (score 4):

> Progress in academia is in their publications.

Yes, they are. But publications do not come out of the blue. You need to do reviews to learn the state of the art. You need to attend conferences, to interact with other people. You need to work on projects, to learn how to follow (at your PhD beginning) and how to lead (when you become a PI). You need to learn how to write proposals to fund your research. You need to supervise undergraduate theses, although they might not always lead to a publication. And most of all, you need a network of people that would write reference letters for you, cite your papers, collaborate with you on proposals and saying NO to everything, as your last post suggested is a sure way to end up jobless.

The projects you participate in, the interaction you have with other scientists, the reviews you have to do, the conferences you attend might seem like a distraction to you, instead of sitting in your desk and doing "your" research. But science and research is a social activity and it is usually your network (as sad as it may seem) that gets you a job and not your research. Participating in many research activities, leads to more ideas and then your research becomes more diverse, instead of rehashing the same line of research which is the usual outcome of people working in isolation. So, suggesting that a PhD student should only focus on a very narrow line of research (which considers his) and avoids any other scientific activity (because it steals time from "his" main research) is a very bad advice.